# Gradle dependency, where is it used in the project

Tags: gradle

Is there a way to search for all or a particular dependency in the project and see where it is used, like which files is it imported into?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`dependencyInsight` task](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#example_using_the_dependency_insight_report_for_a_given_dependency). However this report task is only executed on the project on which it is invoked. So in a multi project you will have to specify it for every project. Also I would recommend using the `--configuration` filter otherwise the output can be pretty large given the number of configurations that can be resolved in a typical project.

Or you can define a dedicated task for this in every project, using a Gradle property passed on the command line argument to specify which dependency to search for, with a task in your root project that depends on them all, giving you an easy invocation mechanism.